# Is such singularity Gorenstein?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral normal scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ with isolated singularity at a closed point $p$. Suppose that $X$ admits a rational resolution $f:Y\to X$ with the exceptional set equals to the fiber $C:=f^{-1}(p)$. It is known that $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is Cohen-Macaulay.  Now assume more that $f$ is also small (i.e. the fiber $C$ is of codimension at least $2$), then is it necessary that $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is Gorenstein?

Answer (score 3):

No. For instance, the cone over $\mathbb{P}^m \times \mathbb{P}^n$ has a small resolution for all $m$ and $n$, but the singularity is Gorenstein only when $m = n$.

Comment: If we assume more that the local ring  $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is complete, then is it Gorenstein?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: A noetherian local ring is Gorenstein if and only if its completion is so.

Comment: Is the formal fiber of $f$ at $p$ is still smooth?

Comment: In this example, is it a rational singularity?